# DS&A: How to optimize a schedule so that empty slots are at the end of the day?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, graph-theory

I'm writing a small program to schedule therapists and patients based on their availability. I'm able to generate an initial schedule, but am currently trying to optimize the therapists' schedules so that, when possible, any empty slots are at the end of the day (and they can go home early!).

I'm not too worried about time or space complexity because the numbers in question are pretty small (there are always 8 slots in the day).

My idea is a recursive method that takes an empty slot and, starting with the appointments at the end of the day, checks if any sessions can be moved to that slot. Once an appointment has been moved into the empty slot, we take the new empty slot and call the method again with that. The success base case is that the given empty slot is at the end of the day, and the failure base case is that no appointments can be moved to the given empty slot.

Here is a slightly simplified version of my code. It's currently getting stuck in a loop where it trades two appointments back and forth forever. I could keep trace of the index and make sure that an appointment never moves back to where it came from, but then I think I'd just run into a 3-appointment loop.

```
emptySlots.forEach((emptySlot: ValidTime) => {
  const swapAppts = (slotToFill: ValidTime): boolean => { 
     if (slotToFill === lastSlot) return true;

     for (let i = 1; i < apptsLastToFirst.length; i++) {
        let appointment: Appointment = apptsLastToFirst[i];
        if (availability[slotToFill].patients[appointment.patient] === true) {
          const nextSlotToFill: ValidTime = appointment.time;
          appointment.time = slotToFill;
          apptsLastToFirst.sort((a: Appointment, b: Appointment) => b.time.localeCompare(a.time));
          return swapAppts(nextSlotToFill);
        }
     }
     return false;
  };
  if (swapAppts(emptySlot)) {
    // TBD - update state with new appointments
  }
}
```

The input `slotToFill` is a `ValidTime` string (which has to be one of the possible time slots in the schedule) and the appointments array `apptsLastToFirst` looks like this.

```
[
  { patient: "Pt 2", therapist: "Raul", time: "1630" },
  { patient: "Pt 2", therapist: "Raul", time: "1530" },
​  { patient: "Pt 1", therapist: "Raul", time: "1345" },
​  { patient: "Pt 6", therapist: "Raul", time: "1300" },
  { patient: "Pt 6", therapist: "Raul", time: "1115" },
  { patient: "Pt 1", therapist: "Raul", time: "1030" },
  { patient: "Pt 5", therapist: "Raul", time: "0930" }
]
```

A potentially confusing line in that code is `availability[slotToFill].patients[appointment.patient] === true` - this checks an availability object to see if the patient is available during that time slot (they have many other appointments throughout the day, so we have to make sure they're available before swapping).

Does anyone know 1) how I could adjust this method to avoid loops or 2) a better way to go about solving this? Conceptually it feels like a directed graph problem, and I would imagine there's already an existing algorithm to solve it, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Your `forEach` callback defines `swapAppts` -- that's all it does. It doesn't call it. So nothing really happens. Could you provide example input and expected output for it, and fix the code so it (1) initialises the input (`apptsLastToFirst`, `emptySlots`), (2) include code on which this code depends, like `isAvailable` (3) somehow returns something or prints something that counts as a result.

Comment: @trincot Whoops, I opted to not include all of that info because I thought it would clutter up the question too much lol - I'll add it back!

Comment: If you can exclude code, then that is preferable, but what remains should be self-contained.

Comment: Updated - let me know if it still doesn't have enough information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for recursion.

```
LOOP until no more reschedules can be found
   LOOP E over empty slots
       IF E at end of day
           CONTINUE
       LOOP F over filled slots
           IF F at end of day
                IF reschedule is feasible
                    Reschedule F to E
                    BREAK out of LOOP E
```

Care needs to be taken with the definition of end of the day - it is the last slot that has no filled slots later on.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
X X O X O X O O
```

7 and 8 are the unfilled end of day slots

6 is the filled end of day slot

So the algorithm will move 6 to 3

---

Your input not only is missing patient availability it is weirdly inefficient

Suggest:

Lines that specify patient availability

```
p index slotlist
```

Lines that specify the schedule

```
s patientIndex therapistIndex slot
```

For example, a simple worst case

```
p 1 3 4 5
p 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
s 1 1 5
s 2 1 7
```

Comment: Hi, if I understand your psuedocode correctly (which I might not), it's assuming that we will always be able to reschedule once we find where things need to go. My problem is that we often can't - if the patient scheduled at 6 is not available at 3, then we would have to move another patient to 3, and then try to move the patient at 6 into their spot, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the definition of end of day! I hadn't taken that into account

Comment: It is customary to upvote an answer you find useful.

Comment: " if the patient scheduled at 6 is not available"  You do not have this information in your input, so no algorithm that doesn't use magic will be able to handle this.

Comment: I have added the line where the magic happens